# How to use dynamic data as a parameter with the date_create_from_format function in PHP

Tags: php, function, date, timestamp

I have string naming the date and time in the format of `d-m-Y_h-i-sa`

an example being `'10-01-2019_03-31-06pm'`

I want to turn this into a unix timestamp.

So I use `$date = date_create_from_format('d-m-Y_h-i-sa', '10-01-2019_03-31-06pm')`

and then `echo date_timestamp_get($date)`

This works, but the problem is that I won't always be passing through literal strings for the second parameter of the function.. as instead I want to use data from a table in a database so that it's dynamic.

an example being `$row['file_name']`

However if I do `$date = date_create_from_format('d-m-Y_h-i-sa', $row['file_name'])`

and then `echo date_timestamp_get($date)`

it doesn't echo anything.

I have done `var_dump($row['file_name'])` and it confirms it is definitely a string.. so I don't understand why the first way works (using a literal string) but the second way won't work (when that's also classed as a string)

Comment: $row['file_name'] is this column's datatype timestamp ?

Comment: @RambarunKomaljeet no it's nvarchar(255)

Comment: What do you get when you var_dump($date) or echo $date ?

Comment: @RambarunKomaljeet when I `echo $date` I get nothing, when I `var_dump($date)` I get bool(false)

Comment: is $row['filename'] in the same format as 'd-m-Y_h-i-sa' ?

Comment: @RambarunKomaljeet yes everything in the column $row['file_name'] is in format d-m-Y_h-i-sa

Comment: Why on Earth would you have a date in a column called `file_name`

Comment: @RiggsFolly because the items listed in the `file_name` column are files which are named based on a date and time

Comment: ok, so are you sure that all these file_name dates are in this format?

Comment: yes. `21-01-2019_02-15-34pm` is an example of one of the file names, which is in DD-MM-YYYY_HH-MM-SSam/pm format `d-m-Y_h-i-sa`. all the files are named this way

Comment: try checking if `$date` is FALSE after this statement `$date = date_create_from_format('d-m-Y_h-i-sa', $row['file_name'])`

Answer (score 0):

In  `$date = date_create_from_format('d-m-Y_h-i-sa', '$row['file_name']')` there should be no quotes around `$row['file_name]` because doing so gives this as a string, not the value. So instead do

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d-m-Y_h-i-sa', $row['file_name'])
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo in my question on here (which I've now revised).. my actual code does not use quotes around `$row['file_name']` but it still doesn't work